# I have a cursor which retrieves record and put it in an object. 1 of the record is the ID of another table, how do get data from other table?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SubjectComment WHERE subjectQuestionId = $subjectQuestionId", null)
cursor.use {
    while (it.moveToNext()) {
        with(cursor) {
            var subjectComment = SubjectComment()
            subjectComment.commentId = getLong(0).toInt()
            subjectComment.subjectQuestionId = getLong(1).toInt()
            subjectComment.comment = getString(2)
            subjectComment.uploadedBy = getLong(3).toInt()
            subjectComment.dateCreated = getString(4)

            subjectCommentList.add(subjectComment)
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my code. In this query, I retrieve comments on a question with a RecyclerView and add it into a `subjectCommentList` so that I can display all the comments. However, I have an `"uploadedBy"` column which contains an Int `ID` of a `Student` table. I would want to retrieve the `Name` from the `Student` table with this `ID`, but how do I go around doing that? I've tried using another cursor inside `with(cursor {   }` but it didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get fields from both fields with tables' join.
Try to change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM SubjectComment LEFT JOIN Student ON SubjectComment.uploadedBy = Student.id WHERE subjectQuestionId = $subjectQuestionId
```

As a result you'll get fields from both tables.

You can specify what fields you want to get explicitly:

```
SELECT sub.*,Student.name FROM SubjectComment as sub LEFT JOIN Student ON sub.uploadedBy = Student.id WHERE subjectQuestionId = $subjectQuestionId
```

If "uploadedBy" - is a Foreign Key (so it cannot be empty), you can in your query replace "Left Join" with "Inner Join"

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. As you can see from my query, I'm getting 5 columns from the table SubjectComment. By doing a left join, can I manipulate it so that I will be able to get the Name of Student table as the 6th Column? Eventually I can just add another object member subjectComment.uploadedByName for example, and append it as subjectComment.uploadedByName = getString(5) ?

Comment: Cursor holds all columns that are present in your query (that is true both for simple queries and for tables' joins), the cursor columns' names are equal to fields' names in your query (or their aliases). But to get some value from cursor it is better not to use fixed column's numbers, like `getString(5)`. Instead you can get column index by filed's name, like: `getString(getColumnIndex("name")`. And yes, to put student's name inside `SubjectComment` object  it should have separate string column, like `uploadedByName`